# Scala, Playframework Debugging like (PHP var_dump or die)

Tags: scala, debugging, playframework

How to debug Scala and playframework? and would like to know if there's method like var_dump and die like used in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an IDE you can run 'play debug', then connect with your IDE and put a breakpoint at the beginning of the controller and then inspect the content of the request. You can find more information in [the Playframework documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/IDE).
If you don't use an IDE you can still use a standalone Java debugger, I've had luck with [JSwat](https://github.com/nlfiedler/jswat).

Comment: Definitely agree with IgorR I will only add that using IDE's debugger far better then _damaging_ source code, which brains new problems. Using IDE debugger, you can check much more things (ie. all values assigned before the breakpoint) also can mute debugger at once and return to normal program flow.